# Dropdownlistfor is not fetching the selected value in MVC Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am appending the option value to the select element by using JavaScript and I have only one option value while posting the form.

Once my JavaScript added the option to select, my html code will be like below.

[image: Html Script Image]

My view Model is not getting the selected value in drop down list. Please help me.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PostAdCategoryID, new List<SelectListItem> 
   {new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" } },
     "Select Category", new Dictionary<string, object>
      {
          { "class", "form-control col-lg-5" },
          { "id", "selectCategory" },
          { "data-toggle", "modal" },
          { "data-target", "#categoryModal" }
      })
```

**Model**

```
public class PostAdFormViewModel
{
    // I have other objects and those are able to fetch the values (text boxes)
    [Required]
    public int PostAdCategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controler**

```
public ActionResult PostNewAd(PostAdFormViewModel viewModel)
{

}
```

Comment: please post the javascript function or form for the data pass to controller

Comment: You need to show your code! (and the image shows a `disabled` attribute - disabled controls do not submit a value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add just one option to the select input is not enough, you have to add the select option but it must have the selected attribute:

```
<option selected="selected" value="9">TVS</option>
```

For what you have posted so far the selected attribute is missing, so, though it have just one option this unique options is "visual selected" (because there is just one option) but it is not really selected (missing the attribute).

Looking at the information you have provided, the other things look like are ok. If still this does not work I suggest the see what/how is being sent to the server (F12 in browser).

Have a nice weekend. Regards.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Dime2lo

Comment: I implemented the logic to add selected in java script and it works perfectly.. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked don't forget to mark the answer as the right one. Regards.